# Finding if `body` tag has class on Pop-up Window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a webpage where you can blow up the content into a pop up window using `window.open`.

The pop-up will have a `class` on its `body` called `pop-up`.  Important to note, both windows use the same JavaScript file where it handles the `click` events.

I want to know if I am clicking in the pop-up or in the main (parent) window.  Since the `HTML` is going to be basically the same.

Here is how I am attempting to do this. I maintain a global variable of the last clicked element and this seems to work:

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
    window.lastElementClicked = event.target;
    g_lastClicked = window.lastElementClicked;
});
```

I know this is good because when I check the `tagName` of the last clicked element it is always correct.

Then when I want to check "Where Am I" I wanted to do this:

```
    var fromPopup = $(g_lastClicked).closest("body").hasClass("pop-up"); // the line in question
    alert(fromPopup);
    if (fromPopup) {
        // unrelated; I need a check to do resizing if I am in the pop-up
        var height = $(window).height();
        $("#cvApplication").height(height - 120);
    }
```

So it will check the last element, traverse up the DOM to the body and see if it has the `class`.  I get `false` every time in the above `alert`.  Is my logic wrong?  Or is there a completely different way I need to be doing this?

Comment: They're separate windows, why do you need to track what element was clicked? Your code lives in two separate, largely-isolated environments (one copy per window).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  Because the two windows use common JS functions and I need to do certain UI things (e.g. resizing) if I am clicking in one vs the other.

Comment: They don't unless you're doing something special to make that happen. Loading the same script file in both windows loads two separate copies into two separate JavaScript environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're separate windows, there's no need to track an "active" element. Each window has its **own** copy of the script and its own variables, event handlers, etc.

All you need in your code is

```
if ($(document.body).hasClass("pop-up")) { // Without the . before pop-up
    // This code is running in the pop-up
} else {
    // This code is running in the main window
}
```

Comment: Ok, well this seems to work.   Although I get false when I first open the window;  but that seems to be a separate issue.

Comment: Ok fixed it, I was calling the code above too soon.  Thanks, marking correct.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked the rest of your code, but you do not use a `.` when checking if an element has a class.

```
var fromPopup = $(g_lastClicked).closest("body").hasClass(".pop-up");
```

should be

```
var fromPopup = $(g_lastClicked).closest("body").hasClass("pop-up");
```

Comment: I actually had it the correct way then i saw a link where it had the `.` and so I tried that.  Neither work.